# really new need help in putting data from pdo into fullcalendar jquery

Tags: php, jquery, pdo, calendar, fullcalendar

I have just started learning PHP and my project i  am working on is for work.I need to be able to input data from my data base which is already populated to

fullcalendar iv managed to get this far but iv gotten stuck on the right way of getting data from database i only need to add the date to the calendar and the user who will be visiting that day. i use PDO not MySQL.

Any help will be much appreciated and will add your name to the bottom of the website once completed

ok so i have the basics set up i think i have events.php, add__events.php, update_events.php and the fullcalendar set up but im lost on how to get the data from my database to the calendar. what i want to put into the calendar is the firstname, lastname and maybe there unic ID

events.php

```
<?php
// Values received via ajax
$title = $_POST['title'];
$start = $_POST['start'];
$end = $_POST['end'];
$url = $_POST['url'];
// connection to the database
try {
$bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=usay visitors', 'root', '');
} catch(Exception $e) {
exit('Unable to connect to database.');
}

// insert the records
$sql = "INSERT INTO evenement (title, start, end, url) VALUES (:title, :start, :end, :url)";
$q = $bdd->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array(':title'=>$title, ':start'=>$start, ':end'=>$end,  ':url'=>$url));
?>
```

update_events.php

```
<?php

/* Values received via ajax */
$id = $_POST['id'];
$title = $_POST['title'];
$start = $_POST['start'];
$end = $_POST['end'];

// connection to the database
try {
 $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=usay visitors', 'root', 'root');
 } catch(Exception $e) {
exit('Unable to connect to database.');
}
 // update the records
$sql = "UPDATE evenement SET title=?, start=?, end=? WHERE id=?";
$q = $bdd->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($title,$start,$end,$id));
?>
```

add_events.php

```
<?php
// Values received via ajax
$title = $_POST['title'];
$start = $_POST['start'];
$end = $_POST['end'];
$url = $_POST['url'];
// connection to the database
try {
$bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=usay visitors', 'root', '');
} catch(Exception $e) {
exit('Unable to connect to database.');
}

// insert the records
$sql = "INSERT INTO evenement (title, start, end, url) VALUES (:title, :start, :end, :url)";
$q = $bdd->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array(':title'=>$title, ':start'=>$start, ':end'=>$end,  ':url'=>$url));
?>
```

calendar.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css' />
<script src='fullCalendar/lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='fullCalendar/lib/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js'></script>
<script>

 $(document).ready(function() {
  var date = new Date();
  var d = date.getDate();
  var m = date.getMonth();
  var y = date.getFullYear();

  var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
   editable: true,
   header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
   },

   events: "events.php",

   // Convert the allDay from string to boolean
   eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
    if (event.allDay === 'true') {
     event.allDay = true;
    } else {
     event.allDay = false;
    }
   },
   selectable: true,
   selectHelper: true,
   select: function(start, end, allDay) {
   var title = prompt('Event Title:');
   var url = prompt('Type Event url, if exits:');
   if (title) {
   var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
   var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(end, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
   $.ajax({
   events: 'add_events.php',
   data: 'title='+ title+'&start='+ start +'&end='+ end +'&url='+ url ,
   type: "POST",
   success: function(json) {
   alert('Added Successfully');
   }
   });
   calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
   {
   title: title,
   start: start,
   end: end,
   allDay: allDay
   },
   true // make the event "stick"
   );
   }
   calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
   },

   editable: true,
   eventDrop: function(event, delta) {
   var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
   var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.end, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
   $.ajax({
   event: 'update_events.php',
   data: 'title='+ event.title+'&start='+ start +'&end='+ end +'&id='+ event.id ,
   type: "POST",
   success: function(json) {
    alert("Updated Successfully");
   }
   });
   },
   eventResize: function(event) {
   var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
   var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.end, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
   $.ajax({
    events: 'update_events.php',
    data: 'title='+ event.title+'&start='+ start +'&end='+ end +'&id='+ event.id ,
    type: "POST",
    success: function(json) {
     alert("Updated Successfully");
    }
   });

}

  });

 });

</script>
<style>

 body {
  margin-top: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;

  }


 #calendar {
  width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  }

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id='calendar'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: See the fullcalendar documentation regarding the [event source object](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Source_Object/). The easiest solution for you would likely be to tell fullcalendar to read from a json feed, and have a PHP script generate it (eg using [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)).

Comment: this is what i have so far

Comment: Side note: "i use PDO not MySQL" They are not mutually exclusive. PDO is one of the PHP code libraries available for communicating with databases. It supports communication with MySQL, among others. Did you mean "i use PDO not mysqli"? mysqli is an alternative PHP code library for talking to MySQL databases. Just wanted to make sure you understand the tools you are using.

Comment: Anyway, you've set "events.php" as the source of your calendar events, which on the face of it is a sensible thing to do, but the code you've shown for that file appears to be _inserting_ data when it should be _selecting_ data and returning it in the format specified by fullCalendar. That's your problem in a nutshell.

Comment: sorry i thought you could only use PDO or Mysqli and if you try and use them both it courses issues.. im still really new to PHP but have fun trying to complete this task. iv been searching the internet on how to input data from my Data base into this fullcalendar i found this code and been trying to convert it but i think iv read it wrong on what this code can do thanks for replying to this post your helping alot

Comment: thanks for the info changed where i was getting the data from to Select * FROM visitors                                    because i messed up on that since data isn't the name of the table. on my calendar i am now getting a blue box on days i have data in my database but there isn't anything ells i need the name of the user to be on the calendar aswell

Comment: can you update the question with the code you have now got please?

Comment: do you return a json in events.php? im not sure but I think fullcalendar is expecting json format of the events. echo json_encode($result)